# Prevent submitting blank input and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I am working with an `input` a `textarea` and a `input` `button` . I need that the `button` is `disabled` when the `input` and `textarea` are **empty**.

This is **Html**

```
<input type="text" class="area">
<textarea name="testo" class="area" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="send" disabled>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.area').on('keyup' , function() {
    if( $('input').val().length > 0 && $('textarea').val().length > 0 ){
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

It works fine, but , if a press the `spacebar` and so it types `blank` chars , the `length`s are not `< 0` anymore and so the `button` not anymore `disabled`. How can I prevent this situation?

Comment: Also, use `input[type="text"]` instead of simply `input` for the first selector. Just to be precise (otherwise it will also select the button, which does not cause any problem in this specific situation, as `val()` will only take into account the first element of the collection - but one change to the markup is enough to break your code).

Comment: Thank you for the hint , but I made a fast jfiddle, the real code in another , is binded on classes and id's . Thank you anyway

Comment: explain downvote please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**`$.trim()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to clean up the values off of leading and trailing spaces

```
if( $.trim($('input').val()).length > 0 && $.trim($('textarea').val()).length > 0 ) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following function definitions that assures you do have a "trim" function available

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim!=="function")
String.prototype.trim=function(){
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")
}
```

now your code should not change the user input... but it should be able to detect if the user only types "spaces"

```
$('.area').on('keyup' , function() {
if( $('input').val().trim().length > 0 && $('textarea').val().trim().length > 0 ){
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text1" value="name"/>
<textarea type="text" id="text2"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="click">click</button>
</form>
if( $('#text1').val().length > 0 && $('text2').val().length > 0 ){
       $('#button1').prop('disabled', false); 
    }
    else {
        $('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.area').on('keyup' , function() {
   if($.trim($('input').val()).length > 0 && $.trim($('textarea').val()).length > 0 ){
       $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
   }
   else {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `trim` function of jquery:

```
$('.area').on('keyup' , function() {
    if($.trim($('input').val()).length > 0 && $.trim(($('textarea').val()).length > 0 ){
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[See the below link. Here i got the answer for this question][1]

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#txtNoSpaces").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/MwEkj/